# Delete sprite added from class

Tags: python, pygame

This is the code for adding sprites from a class:

```
placed = pygame.sprite.Group()
placed.add(StraightPipe((-2,0)))
```

Straight pipe is the name of the class.

How do i remove the same sprite that i just added?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep a reference to the sprite you just created, so that you can [`remove`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.remove) it again:

```
placed = pygame.sprite.Group()
straight_pipe = StraightPipe((-2,0))
placed.add(straight_pipe)

... later ...

placed.remove(straight_pipe)
```

I'm assuming that the `remove` call is in the same [scope](https://pythonspot.com/scope/) as the `add` call. If it's not, you might need to make `straight_pipe` global or add it as a class member, depending on the structure of the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of *Sprites* by [`pygame.sprite.Group.sprites`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). Hence you can access the last element of the *Group* by subscription and kill it by [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill):

```py
placed.sprites()[-1].kill()
```